# Pub/Sub vs Http in Cloud Functions Cron Jobs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I want to make Cron Jobs by using Cloud Functions and Google Scheduler
I know roughly what Publish / Subscribe is, I searched it.
But I still don't get it perfectly even I read it and over again.

there you have to choose one of three kinds (when you set Google Scheduler)

1. Pub / Sub
2. App engine http
3. Http (just)

Which one of these three should I choose?

I want to delete or set or update the some user's information data set stored in Firestore in my Android app every night at 12 pm every night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the following:

1. You use Cloud Function to update data
2. You're looking for a scheduler solution running in GCP

Based on those assumptions, you can refer to this article from Google: https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule
and the call flow will be: Cloud Scheduler -> Cloud Pub/Sub -> Cloud Function -> Cloud Firestore

It's also mentioned that why Cloud Pub/Sub is chosen over HTTP(S), you're also recommended to use Cloud Pub/Sub due to security concern, but you should make your own decision if authentication is not required here.

Answer (score 1):

To schedule task, you can deploy App Engine service that will call cloud Firestore manager to delete data. Than you can [schedule calls with App Engine Cron Service as described in the Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/schedule-export).